# array key order not same as initliazed in python

Tags: python

i was working with arrays in python , since i am new to python, so i am unable to figure out

when i initialize the array

```
myarray = {"months":[],"jan":[],"feb":[],"mar":[],"apr":[],"may":[],"jun":[],"jul":[],"aug":[],"sep":[],"oct":[],"nov":[],"dec":[]}
```

but after some manipulation , when i do the "print(myarray)"

i notice that all the keys are jumbled. but i want to retain all these keys in same order.

i have searched the internet but couldnt find anything that helps me in retaining the key order.

so if anybody can help me

Thanks

Comment: That's a dictionary, not an array, and dictionaries are not ordered.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about arrays, you have defined a dictionary. See also  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: @Mark using the wrong term does not make a question off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not an array, that is a `dict`.  Dictionaries do not maintain key order.

If you care about maintaining the ordering of your keys, use an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: Note that OrderedDict is available only with later versions of python 2.7